# Let $R$ be a finite dimensional $F$-algebra, where $F$ is a field. Show that the following conditions are equivalent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

If $R$ is a finite ring, then we know that the following are equivalent: 
i. $R$ is a division ring. 
ii. $R$ is nontrivial and if $r$,$s \in R$, with $rs=0$, then either $r=0$ or $s=0$. 
$\textbf{NOTE:}$ A commutative ring that satisfies (ii) is called an *integral domain* or sometimes just a *domain*. The problem tells us that finite domains are fields.

Let $R$ be a finite dimensional $F$-algebra, where $F$ is a field. Show that conditions (i) and (ii) from above are equivalent in this case, too.

---

I am not familiar with the definition of $F$-algebra. So that line is confusing me hence I cannot start this problem.

Comment: An [$F$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field) is a vector space over $F$ equipped with a bilinear product

Comment: An $F$-algebra is simultaneously an $F$-vector space and a ring, with the same addition. For example the complex numbers or the quaternions form $\Bbb R$-algebras.

Comment: By talking about algebras instead of rings, how does this change the proof? Are elements of $R$ now vectors?

Comment: The proof barely changes. Elements of $R$ are indeed vectors--you can think of them concretely as finite length column vectors whose entries are in $F$.

Answer (score 1):

An (associative unital) $F$-algebra is simultaneously a vector space over $F$ and a ring.
One formal definition is that $R$ is a ring equipped with a ring homomorphism $F\to R$.
(This induces multiplication by elements of $F$, and conversely, consider the map $c\mapsto c\cdot 1$ where $c\in F,\ 1\in R$.)

Classic examples are the complex numbers, split complex numbers and quaternions over $\Bbb R$.

The proof is similar to the finite case: for a nonzero $r\in R$, the map $\varphi_r:x\mapsto rx$ is injective by hypothesis.
Note also that $\varphi_r$ is an $F$-linear endomorphism of $R$, and since $R$ is finite dimensional, it must be an $F$-isomorphism, in particular it's surjective, so there's an $x\in R$ such that $rx=1$.

Comment: Actually, the finite case is a special case of the statement for finite dimensional algebras, because the minimal subring of a finite ring without zero divisors is a field. But of course the direct proof is easy as well.